# Ionic/Angular Application Show a changing graphic based on JSON property

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm looking for some advice on a task I'm trying to tackle.

I'm looking to add a picture like the one shown below to my ionic/angular application. This is the default and how the picture would show to start.

[image]

My Application will then receive JSON objects with a property of PalletPosition.

If PalletPosition = 4 I would want the graphic to change to the one below.

[image]

So I'm trying to find out the best way to make this happen. If this doesn't make sense I would be happy to elaborate.

Comment: you can use `<div *ngIf="yourLoop.PalletPosition = '4'">Showshow 4</div>`

Comment: would that then require a different picture for all scenarios? I thought of doing it with 4 different pictures with the show/hide approach but was hoping there was a better way of doing this.